# NumberFormatException displays

Tags: java, mysql, sql, servlets

This is my form . I send the parameters to a servlet where i made an update query , but the query is not executed, because it shows NumberFormatException.

```
  `<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="updateS" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" >Update table</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Roll no:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="roll" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" value=""/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Class:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="class" value=""/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Address:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="address" value=""/></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Update"/></td>
                <td><input type="reset" value="Reset"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Here is the servlet , at line 83 numberformatException occurs.

```
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse       response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
     processRequest(request, response);
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String rollno=request.getParameter("roll");
    **int roll= Integer.valueOf(rollno);**
    String classname=request.getParameter("class");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
    System.out.println(address);
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kamal", "root", "123");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update result set name=?, class=?, address=? where rollno=?");

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, classname);
        ps.setString(3, address);
        ps.setInt(4, roll);

        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{

    }
}
```

I changed the above code as below, but problem remains as it is.

```
      @Override
      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    processRequest(request, response);
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     String rollno=request.getParameter("roll");
     int roll  = 0;

   if(rollno!=null && !rollno.trim().equals("")){
     roll  = Integer.parseInt(rollno);
   }

    String classname=request.getParameter("class");
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String address = request.getParameter("address");
        System.out.println(address);
       try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             Connection con =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kamal", "root", "123");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("update result set name=?, class=?, address=? where rollno=?");

            ps.setString(1, name);
            ps.setString(2, classname);
            ps.setString(3, address);
            ps.setInt(4, roll);

           ps.executeUpdate();
         } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

`

Comment: What is the value of the string `rollno` right before you try to parse it as an integer?

Comment: The value was 2 which is also a primary key . it is an intiger column so i cast the string value to integer.

Comment: From what I can see, only `Integer.valueOf` is throwing a `NumberFormatException`.  Are you _certain_ that the string `rollno` is only a single character `2` ?

Comment: in the above form at the input field of roll : i put 2 as string character, in the database , the rollno column is integer, so i had to cast it in integer class.

Comment: try trimming the value of rollno

Comment: is there any problem in the update query?

Comment: @RidwanulHaque You're not understanding the question.  If `rollno` has other stuff in there, besides digits, it _won't_ work.

Comment: Pls can you add first line of exception?

Comment: 26-Oct-2016 11:00:42.669 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-82] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [updateS] in context with path [/WebApplication2] threw exception
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
 at updateS.doPost(updateS.java:83)

Comment: Didn't you see this one "threw exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: null ". See you parse null value according to exception. Pls use following answer.

Comment: Simply you can use `Integer.parseInt(rollno)` for parsing, You have to check value of "roll" parameter using javascript validation on your HTML side

Answer (score 1):

According to your exception you parse null value to Integer.valueOf() method. 
    Pls use this one for avoid exception.

```
int roll  = 0;

 if(rollno!=null && !rollno.trim().equals("")){
      roll  = Integer.parseInt(rollno);
 }
```

Then use this way:

```
public Integer isInteger(String str) {
int roll=0;
try {
   roll= Integer.parseInt(str);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return 0; // The string isn't a valid number
}
   return roll; 
}

int roll = this.isInteger(rollno); Use this on your code
```

Comment: i used ur solution instead of the **int roll= Integer.valueOf(rollno);** line, but problem still same.

Comment: Try using `Integer.parseInt(rollno.trim())`

Comment: I changed answer pls can you try now.

Comment: Pls can you paste this output here? System.out.println(request.getParameter("roll"));

Comment: @ChandanaKumara sir nothing gets printed in the console.

Comment: Thats the reason. You are getting empty (" ") string. Pls use above code.

Comment: i used the same code in another select query it worked but it does not work in this update query.

Comment: This is not a sql problem.

Comment: Are you getting again numberformatexception? or another exception

Comment: @ChandanaKumara sir again same numberformatexception , sir what can i do now? should i give up this project? My another project worked with same code , may i send u that source code?

Comment: pls can you change form tag as this and check. <form action="updateS" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>

Comment: @ChandanaKumara sir null prints in the console

Comment: I thinks your class file not build properly. you have previous class file. Pls build your project.

Comment: At last it works, but i dont know why. I just delete all other built in methods from the servlet.

Comment: @ChandanaKumara thanx a lot.

Comment: Because your class did not build properly after above modification. It was running previous version. I mean .class file not created well.

Answer (score 0):

**This is another project, it worked with the same code.**

```
      <html>
       <head>
       <title>TODO supply a title</title>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-  scale=1.0">
       </head>
       <body>
       <form action="Servlet" method="POST">
        Enter your Rollno:<input type="text" name="roll"/><br/>

        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

**This is that servlet**

```
 public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {

                        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,     HttpServletResponse response)
                       throws ServletException, IOException {

                         response.setContentType("text/html");
                           PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

                      String rollno = request.getParameter("roll");
                    int roll = Integer.valueOf(rollno);

                     try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection con =    DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kamal", "root", "123");

                           PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from result where rollno=?");

                        ps.setInt(1, roll);

                out.print("<table width=50% border=1>");
                out.print("<caption>Result:</caption>");

                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                /* Printing column names */
                ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                int total = rsmd.getColumnCount();
                out.print("<tr>");
                for (int i = 1; i <= total; i++) {
                    out.print("<th>" + rsmd.getColumnName(i) + "</th>");
                }

                out.print("</tr>");

                /* Printing result */
                while (rs.next()) {
                    out.print("<tr><td>" + rs.getInt(1) + "</td><td>" + rs.getString(2) +"</td><td>"+rs.getString(3)+"</td><td>"+rs.getString(4)+"</td> </tr>");             
        }  

        out.print("</table>");

            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }

        }

    }
```